# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment on element attribute

Tags: javascript

I am creating a video player with dashjs. I seem to get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment on element attribute" when I try to add a data attribute to my function for creating the `<video>` element inside my video-container element.

```
    function createVideoElement() {
        videoElement = document.createElement("video");
        videoElement.id = "video";
        videoContainer = document.getElementById("video-container");
        videoElement.autoplay = false;
        videoElement.src = "";
        videoElement.controls = true;
        videoElement.data-video-id = window.datavideoId;
        videoContainer.appendChild(videoElement);
        window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackNav);
        return videoElement;
    }
```

The error occurs at:-

```
videoElement.data-video-id = window.datavideoId;
```

Ok, so it doesn't like my "data-video-id". If I remove the data-video-id line, the `<video>` element is created with the appropriate attributes. How else can I do this without getting this error?

Comment: There is no such 'data-video-id' attribute is there for video element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `-` as a part of variable name, because it is interpreted as minus (Subtraction) operator.

To fix this, you can try `videoElement['data-video-id'] = window.datavideoId;` or better `videoElement.setAttribute('data-video-id', window.datavideoId);`

Comment: Yep, I figured it out just as you posted this. videoElement.setAttribute('data-video-id', window.datavideoId); works perfectly. Thanks!